# error en migracion Paperclip en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hola es que cada vez que doy la migración me tira un error y no me deja hacer la migración.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

```
 gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
 gem "spring", group: :development
```

las gemas que tengo instaladas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que dice el error es que debes especificar en tus migraciones la versión de Rails con la que estás trabajando; esto lo haces agregando la versión entre corchetes directamente en la clase que heredas de `ActiveRecord::Migration`; por  ejemplo, el mensaje de error muestra como se haría para `Rails 4.2`:

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToProductossnack < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  ...
end
```

En tu caso, que estás utilizando la versión `5.1.1` entonces harías lo siguiente:

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToProductossnack < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  ...
end
```

El archivo que debes editar es: *db/migrate/20170822195101_add_attachment_avatar_to_productossnack.rb*; el cual  se generó cuando ejecutaste el comando:

```
$ rails generate paperclip productosnack avatar
```

Comment: hola como seria la migración en ese momento en rails 5.1.1 como hago esa migraciones. @Gerry

Comment: @juangomez Revisa la respuesta actualizada, he puesto más claro cuál es el archivo que debes editar.

Answer (score 0):

Aún no puedo comentar pero ayudandote con tu cometario en la pregunta anterior sería de esta manera la forma de construir la migración.

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToProductossnack < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    add_attachment :productossnack, :avatar
  end

  def down
    remove_attachment :productossnack, :avatar
  end
end
```

Comando:

```
rails g migration AddAttachmentAvatarToProductossnack
```